# yubikey dongle : generate key through pkcs11 failed

Tags: pkcs#11, yubikey

I don't manage to generate rsa private key on yubikey (4 series) with pkcs11 module.

command:

```
#pkcs11-tool -v --module /usr/local/lib64/libykcs11.so --login --login-type so --keypairgen --id 5 --key-type rsa:2048
```

I tried all id allowed (1 to 5)

result:

```
DBG ykcs11.c:1335 (C_Login): Successfully logged in
DBG ykcs11.c:1339 (C_Login): Out
DBG ykcs11.c:612 (C_GetMechanismList): In
DBG ykcs11.c:653 (C_GetMechanismList): Out
....
DBG ykcs11.c:704 (C_GetMechanismInfo): Out
DBG ykcs11.c:3441 (C_GenerateKeyPair): In
DBG ykcs11.c:3482 (C_GenerateKeyPair): Trying to generate a key pair with mechanism 0
DBG ykcs11.c:3484 (C_GenerateKeyPair): Found 9 attributes for the public key and 8 attributes for the private key
DBG ykcs11.c:3526 (C_GenerateKeyPair): Generating key with algorithm 7 in object 90 and 115 in slot 82
DBG ykpiv.c:795 (_ykpiv_transmit): > 0047008205ac0380010700 (11)
DBG ykpiv.c:802 (_ykpiv_transmit): < 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 (258)
DBG ykpiv.c:795 (_ykpiv_transmit): > 00c000000e (5)
DBG ykpiv.c:802 (_ykpiv_transmit): < 6adde27915ecea497d82030100019000 (16)
DBG ykpiv.c:748 (ykpiv_translate_sw): SW_SUCCESS
DBG ykcs11.c:3539 (C_GenerateKeyPair): Unable to generate key pair
DBG ykcs11.c:3613 (C_GenerateKeyPair): Out
DBG ykcs11.c:211 (C_Finalize): In
DBG ykcs11.c:85 (cleanup_session): Cleaning up session 1
DBG ykcs11.c:90 (cleanup_slot): Cleaning up slot 0
DBG ykpiv.c:344 (ykpiv_disconnect): Disconnect card #10218283.
DBG ykcs11.c:253 (C_Finalize): Out
error: PKCS11 function C_GenerateKeyPair failed: rv = CKR_GENERAL_ERROR (0x5)
```

Any idee ?

Thanks